# My copy of "Processing" does not have the "processing.serial" library

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing

I have searched for weeks online for this library.  It is suppose to be built into the core but no matter what I do it can never find the processing.serial library.

Every code I try to run gives me this error msg:

The package "processing.serial" does not exist. You might be missing a library.
No library found for processing.serial
As of release 1.0, libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder.

I am running 1.51 on Windows 7 x64 and have fixed the rx/tx issue already.  Searching my computer for the file turns the same results as searching the internet so far, it doesn't seem to exist.

Looking at the Processing site for the library only gives me syntax for the language.
I'm exhausted in my search.  Please, somebody help this newbie out and tell me what it is that I don't know...
  I'll post the solution to the processing site as soon as it's fixed so nobody has to go through this again.

Your help is so greatly appreciated...

Comment: Does your code start with `import processing.serial.*;`? I could only reproduce your error if I remove the `.*` part from the `import` statement. Maybe that's the cause?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got import processing.serial.*; at the very top of your code and it's still giving you the same error I'd say delete Processing and then download and reinstall it. It sounds like it will save you a lot of time and stress in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

the libraries serial.jar and RXTXcomm.jar are the ones you are looking for, they are located under the /modes/java/libraries/serial/library in you processing installation

Answer (score 0):

to communicate whith usb betwen arduino and processing, I use this library :
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

You need this code for the serial to work :

```
    import processing.serial.*;
    Serial serial;
    int baudrate = 9600;

    void setup() {
    serial = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], baudrate);
    //change the 0 if arduino is not your first com port
    }
```

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not in Android mode while trying to execute a Java program.  Click the little box in the upper right hand corner if it says Android and it will change to Java.